# How to pass varibles from JSP to CSS

Tags: css, jsp, liferay

I have a JSP with the following code:

```
String themeImagesPath = cdnHost + themeContextPath + theme.getImagesPath();
```

I have a CSS file with the following code:

```
.lfr-portlet-toolbar .lfr-toolbar-button.import-button a {
    background-image: url(<%= themeImagesPath %>/common/delete.png);
}
```

If I insert the style directly in to JSP without using a CSS file it works. But when I put the above code into a separate file, it doesn't work.

I want to know if there is a way to pass the variable `themeImagesPath` to the CSS?

Comment: Use jquery to aplply css from inside  of your jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very important concept about JSP and CSS is that, browser only understand HTML and CSS. JSP is processed on the server side. What it sends to the client is, after the process, a output comply with html standard, so the browser knows how to render the page. You can verify the above by "View page source". If you understand these, then you will realize there is no such thing about "CSS accepting the variable pass from JSP" because one is executed on the server and one is executed on the client. To achieve your goal, there are many ways. I name 3 examples here:

1. Create a JSP, and write the CSS rule to it. Since it is a JSP, the server will interpret scriptlet and process the output to the client. Note. Don't be worried about the CSS content is written into a JSP file. HTTP don't care about file extension. It is fine for the browser to treat the JSP as a CSS file as long as the mime type and the CSS syntax is correct.
2. Use embedded CSS to include the rules into the JSP, namely the `<style>` element. Because everything is written in JSP, scriptlet can be interpreted.
3. Use style attribute for the element to assign CSS rules. The reason is the same of point 2. However, this approach is less encouraged because of the code maintainability and readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use server side variables in your CSS file. You can how ever apply the styles as inline style in your JSP and achieve the same effect.

In your JSP, find the elements that you want to set the `background-image` to, and apply inline styles to it, e.g.

```
<a class="import-button" href="#" style="background-image: url(<%= themeImagesPath %>/common/delete.png)"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Nope you can not use these variables in css files. Either you should use inline css or use [saas](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/) if your really wants to use variables in a css file.